# how to install angular when there is no @angular file in the node module folder?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am having trouble installing angular CLI on my system, as I have mistakenly deleted the `@angular` folder from the path: `\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng`

The error I'm getting is:

> npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
> npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
> npm ERR! code EEXIST
> npm ERR! path C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng
> npm ERR! dest C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
> npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, cmd shim 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules@angular\cli\bin\ng' -> 'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng'
> npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng
> npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm
> npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2020-08-23T18_25_29_886Z-debug.log

Comment: What's the command you execute before seeing the error?

Comment: Did you try using `--force` as advised?

Comment: Try to reinstall cli => npm install -g @angular/cli

Comment: No, reinstalling dosent work fr me

Comment: Did anyone found thesolution?